# Mysql 2 select all statements not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, join, echo

I am tring to select 2 tables like so

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT StandItems.*, Stock.* FROM StandItems, Stock 
            WHERE StandItems.StandId = ? AND StandItems.Barcode = Stock.Barcode');
```

This works but when i try something like this, its not working

```
echo StandItems.Barcode
```

But if i do something like this, it works.

```
echo Barcode
```

Is there a way to get it to work by adding the "StandItems" before the columnname because StandItems and Stock have some of the same name so when im trying to echo a column from stock its taking it from standitems

Comment: you'd have to alias the columns and spell out the column names. In other words, don't use `standitems.*` use `standitems.barcode as si_barcode` and `stock.barcode as sbarcode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from the query has column names.  These names do *not* include the table aliases.  So, within the context of the query, you can -- and should -- use qualified names.  But, only the column name itself is used in the result set.

You can control the aliases by using `as`, so you could do:

```
select StandItems.Barcode as StandItems_BarCode
```

for instance and then use `StandItems_Barcode` when referring to the column in the result set.

By the way, your query seems to be missing a `join`.  If you really want a cartesian product between the tables, then be explicit and use `cross join` instead of a comma.

Comment: Thanks, could you show me how to do JOIN on this query

Comment: This doesnt seem to work

$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT StandItems.* AS si, Stock.* AS s FROM StandItems, Stock 
   WHERE si.StandId = ? AND si.Barcode = s.Barcode');

Comment: @DanielLe . . . The code in your comment is not what is in my answer.  You can only alias one column at a time.